# Mercurial: patching with a non tracked branch

Tags: mercurial, patch

I've got an Open Source project tracked with Hg. A collegue did some modification without using any version control, and my version also was modified. Now I want to merge the modification he did ( without any version control ) into my trunk, what's the best operation cycle in this case ?
Thank all,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ask him to make a general patch using `diff` tool and apply it with `patch` on your side.

To have this process passed smoother you'd probably `update` back to the revision your colleague has and then merge 2 heads.